# Where can I find the hosted version of the jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, google-code

Why is there not a reference to the hosted jQuery Validation Plugin anywhere?

Can somewhere share the Google Code link?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no "official" plugin for validation.

To my knowledge, Google doesn't host that plugin (assuming you're referring to [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)).

Although that page does provide a list of links to [Microsoft CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) for hotlinking.

Here they are:

- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js

It even has the localization files, e.g. Russia is http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ru.js.

Comment: for other versions (older and newer) check out the [asp.net ajax library](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Validation_Releases_on_the_CDN_2)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the most current links on the project page: [jQuery Validation Plugin page](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the micosoft hosted version
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js